# Can you explain this sentence

Tags: meaning

" The Amateur Softball Association's roster of umpires has declined to 57,000. "
Reference: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of umpires recorded by the Amateur Softball Association is now at 57,000 individuals. It used to be higher, but the number has been reduced to 57,000 individuals.

Update: From the comments between OP and I: 'association' means 'a group of people organized for a joint purpose.' (Google definition) They could be named 'Amateur Softball Group', but often times 'Association' sounds more formal and 'important'.

Comment: Which meaning of "Association " fits here?

Comment: In this case, 'association' means 'a group of people organized for a joint purpose.' (Google definition) They could be named 'Amateur Softball Group', but often times 'Association' sounds more formal and 'important'.

Comment: is my question  "Which meaning of "Association " fits here?" correct?

Comment: If you reworded your question to ask about what "Association" means in the context of "The Amateur Softball Association's roster of umpires has declined to 57,000." - then yes. In which case, I will update my answer.